# Calculate weekly and monthly total in spreadsheet

Tags: excel, xls, google-sheets

How to calculate weekly sum (sum of last 7 rows printed in 7th row) based on daily values, same question for monthly (based on weekly or daily).
I have tried some formulas but they all failed.

[image]

(first column is date column, not in image)

P.S. sorry for "too localized" and "not constructive" I just don't know how to ask this differently

Comment: probably because there is no attempt to solve the problem in your question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For the week column, you can add a formula like `=IF(WEEKDAY(A8)=7,sum(B2:B8),"")` (to put the sum of the week on Sundays.

For the month column: `=IF(MONTH(A2)<>MONTH(A2+1),SUM(B$2:B2)-SUMIF(A$2:A2,"<"&DATE(YEAR(A2),MONTH(A2),1),B$2:B2),"")`

Comment: Doesnt this week column formula require B2 to be a monday? or actually first sunday has to be b8 (anything above that would require a special case formula to keep sum from resulting in an error?)

Comment: @RossLarson Yes you will need to enter a manual formula in the first few lines if the first sunday is before line 8 but from line 8 on you can copy it downwards.

Answer (score 2):

For weekly column

```
=IF(IFERROR(WEEKNUM(A2)=WEEKNUM(A1), FALSE), "",SUM(B2:B8))
```

for monthly column

```
=IF(IFERROR(MONTH(A2)=MONTH(A1), FALSE), "",SUMIF(A2:A33, "<"&DATE(YEAR(A2),MONTH(A2)+1,1), B2:B33))
```

these should work anywhere. Week & month sums will be listed on first day of week/month (what your sheet seemed to have)

Note: the ranges in sumif are 31 days long. I realize every month isnt 31 days. But they are AT MOST 31 days, and each day will only be included if it's month is correct, so it holds for 28,29, and 30 day months as well. This means the formula WILL work for all months without modification.

Comment: thank you for answer, @assylias monthly formula worked for every month without manual calculation of days in month so I accepted that answer and upvoted yours because I've used daily formula.

Comment: Fair enough (though as a side note, my monthly formula will work for every month without manual calculation of days in month (see my note about why the range is 31 and does not need to be modified for shorter months)). That being said, I am glad your problem is solved. and @assylias does have an equally valid answer and did respond before me so I would say he does deserve the checkmark.