# Summing every first month columns in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to add the sum of the first 7 columns and then the next 7th columns etc in Excel. So for example if I have the below data and I needed to be added weekly,

```
Day 02/01/2017  03/01/2017  04/01/2017  05/01/2017  06/01/2017  07/01/2017  08/01/2017  09/01/2017  10/01/2017  11/01/2017  12/01/2017  13/01/2017  14/01/2017  15/01/2017
Presented Calls 1000    1550    900 1455    789 987 1435    1200    1675    1230    1232    1400    999 650
```

So if I want to add the presented calls from 02/01 - 07/01 this should be sum(B2:H2)

Then the sum of the presented calls from 08/01-15/01 this should be sum(I2:M2)
etc

However at the moment in Excel it is being `sum(B2:H2)` then `sum(C2:I2)` which is incorrect, can anyone help?

Comment: Is it possible the data can be organised as two columns with new rows being added at the bottom rather than new columns on the right? If so you could use a pivot table to calculate the weekly/monthly totals.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Calculate weekly and monthly total in spreadsheet](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11141966/calculate-weekly-and-monthly-total-in-spreadsheet)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the OFFSET() function combined with the COLUMN() function and a bit of arithmetic to get the desired range to sum.
Try entering this formula and fill across.

`=SUM(OFFSET($B$2,0,(COLUMN()-COLUMN($B$2))*7,1,7))`

Comment: Nice work! But good to mention that `offset` is [volatile](http://chandoo.org/wp/2014/03/03/handle-volatile-functions-like-they-are-dynamite/); that means that these formulas are recalculated everytime Excel calculates regardless the data on which the formula depends on has changed or not. This can be very time consumptive in big data sheets.

Comment: that is great thanks you I have also found the following youtube video which helped as well :)

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZbEmZErWdvY